# How to define variable to use only part of cell value?

Tags: python, function, csv, web-scraping, key

I am working on a simple web scraper to download CSV database and images from the CSV. The code I have names downloaded images using scrape order, but I want to use part of url instead.

The code reads following CSV data (example):

| web-scraper-order | web-scraper-start-url | foto-src |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1608747401-36 | https://mywebsite.com | /images/display/9000/9524_lg.jpg |

Downloads file https://mywebsite.com/images/display/9000/9524_lg.jpg and names it "1608747401-36.jpg".

Instead I want the file to be named "9524_lg.jpg".

This is the code I use (full code here -> https://github.com/webscraperio/image-downloader/releases):

```
def download_csv_row_images(row, dest_dir):
    for key in row:
        start_url = row['web-scraper-start-url']
        id = row['web-scraper-order']

        if key.endswith("-src"):
            image_url = row[key]
            image_url = urljoin(start_url, image_url)

            image_filename = "%s-%s" % (id, key[0:-4])
            download_image(image_url, dest_dir, image_filename)
```

I presume I need to change "image_filename = "%s-%s" % (id, key[0:-4])". How do I do that to use  the last 11 characters of the url (everything after the last "/") instead?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do something like this

> image_filename = "%s-%s" % (id, key.split("/")[-1])

```
a = 'https://mywebsite.com/images/display/9000/9524_lg.jpg'
b = 'https://mywebsite.com/images/display/9000/123_lg.jpg'
c = 'https://mywebsite.com/images/display/9000/124142_lg.jpg'



my_list = [ a, b, c]

for key in my_list:
    id = 'test'
    
    image_filename = "%s-%s" % (id, key.split("/")[-1])
    print(image_filename)
```

[Print screen from the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IkRn4.png)

Comment: Deleted previous comment because I made a typo. There is no syntax error but this solution doesn't seem to work, I get an error because of too long file name:

`WARNING:Image download error. [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/images/display/9000/9524_lg.jpg-foto-src.jpg'`

Comment: @user1381985  the error you have now is different from the question asked. 
where are you getting this  = ' jpg-foto-src.jpg ' from?

Answer (score 0):

basic answer is to use python's pathlib. for example
from pathlib import Path

```
      mypath =Path(r"https://mywebsite.com/images/display/9000/9524_lg.jpg")
      myname = mypath.name
      print(myname)
```